# Paprefs for CentOS

Tags: centos, centos-7, centos-6, rpm, pulse-audio

Has anyone been successful in installing `paprefs` on either CentOS 6 or CentOS 7?

I tried to unpack the rpm at https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/paprefs-0.9.10-8.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html, but it has too many dependencies without which the installation doesn't proceed and I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
 rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro 

------- On CentOS/RHEL 7 ---------
# yum -y install epel-release && rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

-------- On CentOS/RHEL 6 -----
# yum -y install epel-release && rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm

yum install paprefs
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain *why* you've suggested the above?

Answer (score 0):

If you are to install anything "from" pkgs.org, you must use the instructions provided in a package page.

Particularly in this link, you can see instructions saying to add third party repo:

- > Download latest nux-dextop-release rpm from
  >   http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/

This means you have to literally visit this page in a browser, then hunt down for RPM link of "nux-dextop-release" inside it, e.g. `http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm` then RPM install it.

- > Install nux-dextop-release rpm: `rpm -Uvh nux-dextop-release*rpm`

You can either download the *release* RPM (aka repository configuration) and install it like pkgs.org recommends, but I prefer to skip the download step because `yum` can easily do it:

```
yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

- > Install paprefs rpm package: `yum install paprefs`

Now you can just run that and it will install the package from the third-party repository resolving any dependencies as needed.

That's it.

pkgs.org merely an aggregator/indexer for RPM/apt repositories and it does not host any RPMs.